# Need to identify cable

Tags: identification, cables

Would need to identify this cable for a replacements:
[image: DJI Mavic Mini controller cable]

Codes:
PF000624.02

KW 1947 38

Data Matrix Code: 1STHGCW0020P42

Pins: 15

The cable  is from DJI Mavic Mini controller (CE version) ant it connects the main board with contoller buttons.

Comment: Looks like a custom flex circuit with standard connectors.

Comment: Maybe if you read the QR code it may take you to the supplier's web, you don't lose nothing trying.

Comment: @MarceloCoronel its a Data Matrix code not a QR code. The decoded text is in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a custom flex PCB, so you can't buy it from anyone.

But: the only thing that seems broken is a connector that looks like one of the not soo many mezzanine connector series; since only you have the ability to make specific measurements on this, the best we can offer is a list of potential connectors:

[Digikey category page "mezzanine and array connectors", 28 or 30 contacts in two rows, SMD](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-arrays-edge-type-mezzanine-board-to-board/308?FV=-3%7C22%2C-2%7C362%2C69%7C409393%2C88%7C163489%2C88%7C180528%2Cii2%7C2172%2C-8%7C308&quantity=100&ColumnSort=1000009&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25)

To rework this, you'll probably need a hot air rework station (wouldn't know how to melt the solder on the broken connector, otherwise), the replacement connector, solder and flux; a desoldering wick to get the old solder off the pads once you've removed the connector, and a steady hand (I do recommend not drinking coffee before soldering SMD).